# Yii $form->radioButtonList - CSS to align horizontally

Tags: php, html, yii

I created a form that contain radio button for credit and debit.

I want to display these two in a single. For that I use this command:

```
<?php echo $form>radioButtonList(
         $model, 
         'description',
         array('credit'=>'Credit', 'debit'=>'Debit'),
         array(
            'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'),
            'separator'=>'  ')
         ); ?>
```

Now it works, but I want to store it in database if I give submit it shows an error:

```
Undefined index description.
```

I dont know how to clear that.
I want to add this: `array('name'=>'description')`

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Description'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->radioButtonList(
     $model,
     'description',
     array('credit'=>'Credit','debit'=>'Debit'),
     array(
        'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'),
        'separator'=>'  ')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'description'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please refine your question title. Your question isn't about css, right?

Comment: actually if take out the css it comes by two lines if i add this it gives an undefined index error..i dont know how to give the css and array index..

Answer (score 2):

You can use,

```
$form->field($model, 'description')->inline()->radioList(['C' => 'Credit', 'D' => 'Debit']);
```

See: [yii\bootstrap\ActiveField](http://%20https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/api/2.2/yii-bootstrap-activefield#inline()-detail)

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the mistake and clear it..i change my code like this and it works..

```html
<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Description'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'description',
                    array(  'C' => 'Credit',
                            'D' => 'Debit'),array(
    'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'), // add this code
    'separator'=>'  ','name'=>'description'
) );?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'description'); ?>
        </div>
```